# Как называется конструкция Series[Series]?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
object_cols = list(s[s].index)
```

где `s` - это Series.

Непонятно, что такое `s[s]`?

Догадываюсь, что это какая-то хитро-мудрая синтаксическая штука в Python.
Попробовал посмотреть индексы без нее - выдает уже другой список. Значит, зачем-то `s[s]` был все-таки нужен.

[image]

Подскажите, что это за конструкция и зачем она нужна?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Пример:

```
In [306]: df = pd.DataFrame([["aa", "bb", 1, 3.14, pd.Timestamp("2021-01-01"), "str"]], columns=list("abcdef"), index=[0])

In [307]: df
Out[307]:
    a   b  c     d          e    f
0  aa  bb  1  3.14 2021-01-01  str

In [308]: df.dtypes
Out[308]:
a            object
b            object
c             int64
d           float64
e    datetime64[ns]
f            object
dtype: object
```

создаем булеву маску с True для столбцов с типом данных `object`:

```
In [309]: s = df.dtypes == 'object'

In [310]: s
Out[310]:
a     True
b     True
c    False
d    False
e    False
f     True
dtype: bool
```

теперь можно отфильтровать булеву маску используя ее же:

```
In [311]: s[s]
Out[311]:
a    True
b    True
f    True
dtype: bool
```

если взять индексы получившегося объекта, то получим имена столбцов с типом данных `object`:

```
In [314]: object_cols = s[s].index

In [315]: object_cols
Out[315]: Index(['a', 'b', 'f'], dtype='object')

In [316]: object_cols.to_list()
Out[316]: ['a', 'b', 'f']

In [317]: list(object_cols)
Out[317]: ['a', 'b', 'f']
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Хорошо) Я только сегодня зарегался, так что еще не все тут знаю)